# Twitter hashtag background streaming?

Tags: twitter

Is there any sort of application that you can plug in a hashtag, and have it stream away in the background.

My idea is I want to put a hashtag up on a projector and see tweets stream by (perhaps just certain ones, top tweets and random ones so it doesnt go to fast) as well as have images that people link to show up as well.

Is there anything like this, or should I consider making it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twitterfall](http://www.twitterfall.com/) is a good tool for this.